# Newline on strings concatenation

Tags: javascript, string, concatenation, newline

Why is this not creating a newline?

```
node.textContent = "You lost!\n";
node.textContent += input.textContent + " loses to " + convertNumber(computerSelection);
```

I want a new line to be created after the "You lost!" part. Any help?

Comment: HTML does not honor line breaks unless you have an element like a textarea. You need to use HTML tags like a br element.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way I can add this in JS or do I have to create 2 different elements on my HTML?

Comment: The new line *is* in the text that's produced, but, right, HTML does not *render* "\n" as a visual line break. Does `<br>` work for you?

Comment: @LorenzoZabot **You lost!<br>**

Comment: @epascarello CSS will be sufficient.